# Using jQuery, can I update CSS in a class if text appears on the page somewhere?

Tags: jquery, css

How do I modify the CSS of a class if certain text appears on a page?

Specifically, I have a class that controls a sprite image's visibility and position that I want to update using jQuery based upon text in a div on the page.

My class is named .condDetail and is applied to a div towards the top of the page with the CSS properties visibility:hidden and background-position:0px 0px.

The div below is the exact div I have to work with that I want to control the CSS in the class.

```
<div id="ProductDetail_ProductDetails_div">
   <span itemprop="description">This is an item in Poor Condition</span>
</div>
```

This div will have varying text on a regular basis but will always have Poor Condition, Good Condition, or Fair Condition stated.

I'm trying to get my class to update based upon what that div says the condition is.

If Good Condition, update the class to visibility:visible and background-position:0px 120px.
If Poor Condition, update the class to visibility:visible and background-position: 0px 240px.

....and so on and so on depending on what condition is shown in the div.

Sorry, I'm a newbie.  I know that i can update the class like this:

```
$(".condDetail").css("visibility", "visible");
$(".condDetail").css("background-position", "0px -480px");
```

....But I've spent hours with Firebug trying to figure out how to get it to change based upon the text in that div....

I just can't seem to piece together how to construct the jQuery.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated until i can learn better how to do this on my own.

Comment: how does the text change?

Comment: On the CMS system on our Volusion e-commerce account. All of the additions we make to structure has to be done by jQuery or javascript.  They control the HTML contents of the page by default as it's ASP.net generated pages.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `contains` to check, Example

JS

```
$('#check').click(function() {
    console.log('c');
    $('.condDetail').each(function() {
        console.log('in');
        var el = $(this);
        var text = el.text();
        console.log(text);
        if (text.contains('Good Condition')) {
            //el.show();
            el.css('color', 'green');
        } else if (text.contains('Poor Condition')) {
            //el.hide();
            el.css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="condDetail">
    some text Good Condition more text
</div>
<div class="condDetail">
    some text
</div>
<div class="condDetail">
    some text Poor Condition
</div>

<button id="check">Check</button>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuVzN/2)**

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add a class to the div itself based on condition?

like

```
<div class="anyotherclass good-condition">Good Condition</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is an e-commerce site which we add hundreds of unique products to daily. Adding that to the div would require we touch the page every time a product is created.  We wanted to have it do it automatically as product pages go live.

Comment: What? You generate the page html somewhere.... that's the point when you write the new class. I don't see the problem.

Comment: This is a Volusion e-commerce site.  Adding divs to their ASP.net generated pages has to be done on the fly with javascript / jQuery.  We don't generate the HTML, they do on the back-end.  We simply add products to the database, then it's displayed.  We don't have control like that over the HTML on our pages.  Nor do we have the ability to put in the code where it would normally go as they are ASP generated pages.

Comment: Ah ok so you can only change JS files. It's clear now. :) then other answers citing .contains applies.

Answer (score 0):

As to your question :

- *`Using jQuery, can I update CSS in a class if text appears on the page somewhere?`*, the answer is : yes.
- *`how to get it to change based upon the text in that div ?`* : jQuery allows you to get the text of a div with the `text()` method, example : `$('div').text()` which you can later put in a variable and use in conditionals (see ?). Later on, the best way to go, I think, is by adding some classes with the `addClass` method, and eventually removing some classes with `removeClass`.

Answer (score 0):

another approach would be to look at the index of the phrase in the items text.  working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6cGgx/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#ProductDetail_ProductDetails_div span").text().indexOf("Poor Condition") !=-1 )
    {alert(true) 
    $(".condDetail").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".condDetail").css("background-position", "0px -480px");
    }else if($("#ProductDetail_ProductDetails_div span").text().indexOf("Good Condition") !=-1 ){//stuff 
        alert("foo"); 
    }else if($("#ProductDetail_ProductDetails_div span").text().indexOf("Bad Condition") !=-1 ){//stuff 
        alert("foo"); 
    }
})
```

Personally I'd prefer using `text()` to `html()` since you're working with text not html.

Comment: PERFECT!  Thank you Brad.  After updating the alerts to the varying conditions, it's executing PERFECTLY on all product pages.  Super.  Thanks so much!